# Convert list of Dictionaries with same keys into a single list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dict:

```
output = [{"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.65}]
```

as the key is same in all so I want to merge this and make a list from dictionary.
So far I have tried this:

```
d = []
for k in output.iterkeys():
    d[k] = list(d[k] for d in output)
print d
```

But i gives me an error     `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'`
What I am doing wrong here.

Expected Output :

```
[28.6333, 28.6333, 28.65]
```

To Those who are marking this question as duplicate. I just found out that my query is different as my `type(output) #str` and not int or float thats why when I wrote AttributeError No one points out why a dict is of float values is of type str. This was the reason I am not getting this to work.

When running all the individual answers as a separate programs I got what I wanted but that certainly is not matching the requirements of my program

Comment: The code above wouldn't produce the error you're claiming it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the list of dicts, and get the values, make them iterators (`iter`) to get the only values using `next`:

```
[next(iter(d.values())) for d in output]
```

Similarly, with `map`:

```
[*map(lambda d: next(iter(d.values())), output)]
```

I have picked this approach over the obvious `[k["latitude"] for k in output]` because this would work in a generic way i.e. one does not have to know the name of the key to get the values list.

**Example:**

```
In [85]: output
Out[85]: [{'latitude': 28.6333}, {'latitude': 28.6333}, {'latitude': 28.65}]

In [86]: [next(iter(d.values())) for d in output]
Out[86]: [28.6333, 28.6333, 28.65]

In [87]: [*map(lambda d: next(iter(d.values())), output)]
Out[87]: [28.6333, 28.6333, 28.65]
```

Comment: This does the work for my and I got the expected output

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
[x["latitude"] for x in output]
```

Comment: yes. It will not. I have tried this already

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution.

```
d = [ k["latitude"] for k in output]
```

Comment: yes. It will not. I have tried this already

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha What do you mean "It will not"?? This solution works

Comment: @vaultah What are you talking about a list isn't a list, a list is a list, or are you saying I am not myself and you are not yourself and we are not each other?

Comment: @vaultah I haven't had enough sleep for this question

Answer (score 1):

The `output` variable is a list, but try this:

```
# I assume Python 2.7
output = [{"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.65}]


d = {}
for dic in output:
    for k,v in dic.iteritems():
        if k in d:
            d[k].append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = [v]
print d
```

This will work with multiple keys in the original dictionary, and make one dictionary with all keys as list of all the corresponding values.

It can be improved by using `defaultdict(list)` so that it can be rewritten as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for dic in output:
    for k,v in dic.iteritems():
        d[k].append(v)
print d
```

Both above will output:

```
d = {"latitude": [28.6333, 28.6333, 28.65]}
```

So to get a list of each key, then just lookup d['latitude'] and you have your list of latitudes. (and likewise for longitudes if you have a similar dataset for that.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by below code

```
d=[]
for k in output:
   d.append(k['latitude'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`output` is not a dictionary and therefore `iterkeys()` is not applicable.

The following code should do the trick (using Python 3.6.1):

```
import collections

output = [{"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.65}]

dic = collections.defaultdict(list)

for d in output:
    for k, v in d.items():
        dic[k].append(v)
print (dic)
```